# How to set globals in a different module in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a global in a second module `Module 2` so that i can make references in my Module 1 on those values
I tried the following

```
 Module 2 
 Global firstName As String
```

---

I have a couple of macros in Module 1

```
sub test ()
MsgBox firstName  'firstName is a global from Module 2
end sub
```

---

However, `firstName` was not recognized by any of my macros in Module 1 . How do I declare them correctly ? Do I need to create a sub in Module 2

Comment: Any reason why you are using "Global" not "Public"? "Global" is there for historic reasons, and really no benefits over "Public"

Answer (score 2):

You have to do following:

In `Module2`:

```
Global firstName As String

Sub M2_FN()
firstName = "Testing"
End Sub
```

Then in `Module1`:

```
Sub M1_FN()
Call M2_FN
MsgBox firstName  'firstName is a global from Module 2
End Sub
```

It works as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

In Module 2, I put:

```
Global firstname As String

Sub dural()
    firstname = "XXX"
    Call checkit
End Sub
```

In Module 1, I put:

```
Public Sub checkit()
    MsgBox firstname
End Sub
```

When I run **dural**, the correct text appears.